# eBay API Oauth Refresh Token in PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, ebay-api

Im currently trying to integrate with the eBay API, i have managed to integrate it manually and put in the oAuth key manually to pull data.

What i cannot for the life of me get working is the oAuth refresh token, i keep getting the most indescript error messages from the API just saying "There was an error, please try again".

My current code is below -

```
    function GetTokens($sessionid){
            // Create headers to send with CURL request.
$headers = array
(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization: Basic REMOVED'
);

$xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
    '<FetchTokenRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">'.
         '<SessionID>' . $sessionid . '</SessionID>'.

   '</FetchTokenRequest>';

// Send request to eBay and load response in $response
$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_server . 
"/identity/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
    print_r($response);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

you could at least stop lying to the API. you tell the api `i'm sending you some data in application/x-www-urlencoded format`, and then sending them data in `application/xml` format! maybe that's why you're getting the cryptic error.

you should also complain on their bugtracker, if they have one, about this error, the error should be more descriptive (for example, `failed to parse the request body as appliation/x-www-urlencoded, malformed syntax` along with a http `400 Bad Request` response would be good)

Comment: Ive never worked with such an awkward API, ive already emailed them.

Stupidly, the API specifies that you need to send both !